# Spring 3 MVC ConstraintValidator Validation: isValid method not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am new to Spring 3 MVC and was trying to implemnt `ConstrainValidation` following [this](http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/) but the validation part did not worked, the `isValid` method did not got invoked. Not sure if I am missing something in my configuration, below is what I tried:

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

@Phone
private String phone;

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

**Phone.java**

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {PhoneValidator.class})
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Phone {

String message() default "{Phone}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**PhoneValidator.java**

```
public class PhoneValidator  implements ConstraintValidator<Phone, String>{

@Override
public void initialize(Phone phone) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String phoneField, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    if(phoneField == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return phoneField.matches("[0-9()-\\.]*");
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="done")
public String displaySuccess(@Valid Employee employee,BindingResult result,Model model){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Validation Failed!!!");
        return "display";
    }else{
        System.out.println("Validation Succeeded!!!");
        return "done";
    }

}
```

**Context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.xxx" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Can someone please point out what am I missing? The `Phone` validation is not working, the `isValid` method is also not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `<context:annotation-config />` to `<mvc:annotation-driven />` resoled my problem.

Reference:

[Spring3 MVC: Validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548645/spring3-mvc-validation-not-working)