# Spring3 MVC: Validation not working

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

The gender validation is not working. Even if no values are entered in the gender text field, the form is getting validated successfully without throwing any error.

Below is the Employee class:

```
@Size(min=2,max=10)
private String gender;

// Setters and Getters
```

Below is the Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="done", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateForm(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result, ModelMap m){
    if(result.hasErrors()){
        System.out.println("Validation Failed!!!");
        return "main";
    }else{
        System.out.println("Validation Succeeded!!!");
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Below is the context file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.XXX" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Below is the jsp file:

```
<tr>
            <td>
                Gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="gender"/>
                <form:errors path="gender" cssStyle="color: red;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I am not able to find out whats missing but its something silly. Please help.

Comment: Is HibernateValidator on your classpath?  Did you import @Size from the javax.validation package?

Comment: Both the validators: validation-api.jar and hibernate-validator.jar are present in my classpath. Yes, the package is: `import javax.validation.constraints.Size;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) All of the javax constraints include an implicit "or null" in their pass conditions.  If you want to catch blanks you need to either add `@NotNull`, or reconfigure the web binder to bind blank inputs to empty string instead of null.

2) `<context:annotation-config />` does not turn on Spring 3 dispatcher servlet auto-config magic.  You need to define your own validator bean if you do that.  To enable everything to automagically work you need to use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: I changed the `@Size` to `@NotNull` but still the validation does not work. Please advice.

Comment: You need both annotations

Comment: Still this does not work: `@Size(min=2,max=10) @NotNull
 private String gender;`

Comment: Does validation work for strings of length 1 or 11 and not work for blanks, or nothing works?

Comment: Nothing works. First, tried without any characters, second: tried with a single character.

Comment: what version of hibernate-validator.jar are you using?  It must be 4 or later.

Comment: Is `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your dispatcher servlet?

Comment: hey I dont have any such entry. What I have is `<context:annotation-config />`

Comment: Ok now it works, thanks for the help. In another thread I tried implementing a `ConstraintValidator` yesterday but it did not worked out as well. Can you please have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524282/spring-3-mvc-constraintvalidator-validation-isvalid-method-not-getting-invoked